# What is the term for a special service a firm provides to secure a sale?

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

Is there a standard word to describe something a seller does to secure a sale, particularly an add-on service or package? Like when a car dealer adds a package for new wheels or detailing or a dedicated service support line as encouragement to close soon. A "closer"? "Sweetener"? "White glove"? Value-added service?

Comment: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sweetener)'s definition of 'sweetener' fits, and one example sentence is very similar.

Comment: Also, adding *bells and whistles*, when the add-ons are desirable but cosmetic.

Comment: Would that be a kind of *incentive*? Could you clarify whether this word is intended for use toward other salespeople, the customers, or both?

Comment: "We can throw in a set of floor mats."

Comment: "a bonus" is often over-used.

Comment: Perhaps a clincher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it a **clincher,** [defined by Cambridge as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/clincher)

> a final item to be considered that makes a decision firm after you have been tending toward it, or anything that finally decides a matter

It gives the example sentence:

> The minivan was big enough for eight people and when we heard the price – that was the clincher!

Answer (score 0):

Any place I ever worked always called it your binder

Look up sales binder

Depending on which type of sales, realtor, mortgage broker, insurance agent, pharmaceutical sales rep, binder can be used different ways

Answer (score 0):

**Perks.**

*The perks of this vacuum are free bags and maintenance for one year.*

Perks:: noun INFORMAL

money, goods, or other benefit to which one is entitled as an employee or as a shareholder of a company.
"many agencies are helping to keep personnel at their jobs by providing perks"
an advantage or benefit following from a job or situation.
[Dictionary.com]

The dictionary definition is not too convincing, but I've seen this used frequently in sales discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**Incentive(s)**

Oxford dictionary defines it as

> something that encourages you to do something

An example of which is

> There is an added incentive for you to buy from our catalogue—a free gift with every purchase.